# How to get access to the storage array through the solidity assembler?

Tags: solidity, assembly

If the array is located in memory, then all the elements are in sequence, for example:

```
    uint256 arrLength = arr.length;
    assembly{
        let offset := sload(arrLength)
        res:= mload(add(arrLength,0x20)) //first element
    }
```

But I don’t understand how in the arrays located in the storage? the keys of the elements are generated?
How to get a pointer to an array located in storage?
How to get the value of an element knowing its index?

Answer (score 4):

Each storage variable has its own storage slot whose address is a sequential number of this variable within contract:

```
contract Foo {
  uint internal x; // Storage slot #0
  mapping (uint => uint) internal y; // Storage slot #1
  uint [] internal z; // Storage slot #2
}
```

For atomic variables, such as `x`, this slot holds variable value.

For mapping variables, such as `y`, this slot is not used, but still allocated.

For dynamic array variables, such as `z`, this slot contains array length.

Array data is stored separately in consequent storage slots starting from the slot with address `keccak256 (n)` where `n` is variable sequential number.

So, to access array `z` declared above, you may use the following assembly:

```
function zLength () public view returns (uint r) {
  assembly {
    r := sload (2)
  }
}

function zElement (uint i) public view returns (uint r) {
  assembly {
    mstore (0, 2)
    r := sload (add (keccak256 (0, 32), i))
  }
}
```

Of cause, `keccak256 (2)` should not be calculated every time, such should be substituted as compile-time constant.

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/miscellaneous.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) for more details.