# How to dynamically generate a variable without declaring it in a contract (solidity)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

Is it possible to generate a non-local variable with a function?

Weird question but it's for an exercise my senior asked me to do, I've scoured the web for an answer to no avail.

Instead of declaring the variable:

```
contract MetaCoin{
 uint counter=0;
}
```

Maybe do something like:

```
contract MetaCoint{
function createCounterVariable(){
  //creates counter variable
 }
}
```

It will be functionally identical to the declaring the variable, and other functions can access the generated variable somehow. At least this is how I interpret what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
contract MetaCoint {
    uint public index;
    mapping(uint => uint) public counters;

    function addCounter() external {
        index++;
    }

    function incCounter(uint _index) external {
        require(_index < index, "counter was not created");
        counters[_index]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is okay, but I think an array is more natural. (It avoids having to separately track the length, and it does the bounds checking automatically.)

Comment: @smarx: Yes, I agree. Since counters will be added sequentially, there is really no point in a `mapping` here. I now understand your solution, which is a better (more simplified) solution for the given problem as it is currently stated.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you're trying to do. There's really no such thing as "creating" a state variable. But you might be able to accomplish what you want with a `mapping` or array. Something like this (untested):

```
contract Counters {
    uint256[] public counters;
    event NewCounter(uint256 index);

    function createCounter() external {
        counters.push(0); // "create" a new counter
        emit NewCounter(counters.length - 1); // so the caller can see the ID of the new counter
    }

    function increment(uint256 index) external {
        counters[index] += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I've seen something like accessing the storage of the contract directly like an array, I could be wrong though.

Comment: A little confusing, because there is no `mapping` here.

Comment: @goodvibration I suggested using a `mapping` or an array. I only gave one example, and it uses an array. Does that clear up your confusion?

Comment: Yes, I just figured that a `mapping` would address the issue more accurately, but as you initially stated, it really depends on what this dude is trying to achieve...

Comment: My interpretation is something like this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69931/how-to-get-access-to-the-storage-array-through-the-solidity-assembler
but creating a new variable instead of accessing an existing variable, not sure if it can be done.

Comment: You'll really need to explain what you're actually trying to do. Contract storage is essentially a 256-bit address space, and you can read or write whatever you want by writing some assembly code. But _why_ are you doing that? Generally `mapping`s and arrays are what you should.